# prop not updating subcomponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm really puzzled by something I'm seeing-- I've got a data table that's taking an object as a prop, as well as a string prop used for filtering the data that populates the table:

```
const AudienceMembers = ({audience, search, onChangeHandler}) => {    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        console.log("change to search or audience")
    }, [search, audience])
```

The `audience` object has a `criteria` property that's used for generating the API call used in `fetchData`, and the `fetchData` function should be fired anytime the `search` or the `audience` props change. The parent component calls `AudienceMembers` like this:

```
<AudienceMembers audience={item} search={searchString} onChangeHandler={setTotalCount} />
```

Both `searchString` and `item` are state objects in the parent component, and when I supply a search string the child component updates as expected (with the `change to search or audience` log message). However, changes to the `audience` don't trigger any kind of change in the child, even though I can see the `item` in the parent component changing using the react debug toolbar.

Is there a reason that the prop object wouldn't trigger the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Please, show where you change audience property in parent component.

E.g. following code works fine for me and changes in audience bring the message in console.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
      const AudienceMembers = ({audience, search}) => {    
          React.useEffect(() => {
              console.log("change to search or audience")
          }, [search, audience])
          return (<div>
            <div>
              {JSON.stringify(search)}
            </div>
            <div>
              {JSON.stringify(audience)}
            </div>
          </div>)
      }
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {search: "some", audience: {criteria: 1}};
        }
        changeSearch = () => {
          this.setState({search: "other"})
        }
        changeAudience = () => {
          this.setState({audience: {...this.state.audience, criteria: 2}})
        }
        render() {
          return (<div>
            <button onClick={this.changeSearch}>Change search</button>
            <button onClick={this.changeAudience}>Change audience</button>
            <AudienceMembers audience={this.state.audience} search={this.state.search}/>
          </div>);
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        rootElement
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```